# Dividing one result set by another then display an answer

Tags: javascript, math

Please review the **[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/webfrogs/qAfJv/)**...

I have two date spans here.

After date span one is displays (# of days between two dates), then a third date is input, and a second date span is displayed (# of days between different set of dates).

What I'm trying to do is take...

**Result2 / Result1 = Percentage Earned.**

Here's what I've got so far, but the math isn't working...

```
//Determine Percentage Earned
function percentEarned() {
        $('#labelPercentEarned').text((labelLastDateOfAttendance / labelPayPeriodDays) +" Percentage Earned");
}
```

Comment: How isn't the math working?

Comment: Not sure. Look at the fiddle and you'll see what I mean. I just don't know where I've gone wrong.

Comment: I didn't mean to beg the question, I meant how is your math different than you expect.  That said, I'll glance at the fiddle.

Comment: You have to select the first date (ex: october 1, 2013), and then select the second date (ex: october 29, 2013), and then in the third date, select a date in the middle (ex: october 22, 2013)... all the results are displaying, but the Percentage earned isn't displaying.

Comment: If the number of days between the first span is 29 and the number of days between the second span is 22, then I wanted to see 22/29= 100% and have that answer (100%) displayed in the Percentage Earned label.

Comment: where do you call the funtion `percentEarned` .. i dont see it in the fiddle..  ._.

Comment: @PsychHalf It's there... the bottom function in the JS window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can try `parseInt(labelLastDateOfAttendance)/parseInt(labelPayPeriodDays)`.

So, effectively the function will look like

```
function percentEarned() {
    $('#labelPercentEarned').text(parseInt(labelLastDateOfAttendance)/parseInt(labelPayPeriodDays) +" Percentage Earned");
}
```

Comment: Tried that and it's still not displaying the **Percentage Earned**

Comment: The reason is simple, first of all you are not calling method (percentEarned)from anywhere, hence it is not calling. Second reason is if you are dividing these two variable (NaN) is returning. Thirdly, when i print the div , i see 11 day of attendance and 10 Days in Pay Period for some days, once you use a regex to replace the characters and then divide it will be done.

Comment: It sounds like what you're saying would work. But, I'm not sure what a regex is. Can you provide an example of what you mean? Then I'll mark your answer as correct.

Comment: $("#labelLastDateOfAttendance").html().replace(/[a-zA-Z ]/g,""), this should work for you, use this for both variables.

This should be your final method.

$('#labelPercentEarned').html($("#labelLastDateOfAttendance").html().replace(/[a-zA-Z ]/g,"") /$("#labelPayPeriodDays").html().replace(/[a-zA-Z ]/g,"") ) +" Percentage Earned";

Comment: I used it, but it didn't work. Here's an updated [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/webfrogs/qAfJv/2/) Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: Add method call of percentEarned(); in dateDifference2() at last and then put statement  alert($("#labelLastDateOfAttendance").html().replace(/[a-zA-Z ]/g,"")); in your percentEarned() method and you will see it outputs a number. The reason you don't see the output is because the method never gets called from your js.

Comment: Below code works very nicely, Pls insert this and the method call i suggested. It should work, have checked in your fiddle itself.
function percentEarned() {
   var a= ($("#labelLastDateOfAttendance").html().replace(/[a-zA-Z ]/g,""));
    var b= ($("#labelPayPeriodDays").html().replace(/[a-zA-Z ]/g,""));
    $("#labelPercentEarned").html((a/b)+"Percentage Earned");
}

Comment: Ok. Now we're getting somewhere... A little math and some toFixed() and I'll be good. Thanks!